# Merge statement not matched with the ON Clause in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, merge

I have oracle sql merge statement query in which i want to merge the data from `PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC` to `TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC` table.
The ID are sequence generated in `PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC` table. So i always want to get the data into `TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC` table with the ID greater than the ID from `PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC`. So that i will always want to insert the latest data into the `TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC` table when i execute the query. I tried this query but not resulting the latest data.

```
merge into TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC TSM
using (
   select * from
(select ID,PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,PROCESS_START_DATE from 
PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC@FONIC_RETAIL) where rownum<=1000
) data
ON (TSM.ID > data.ID)
when not matched then
insert(ID,PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,PROCESS_START_DATE)
values(data.ID,data.PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,data.PROCESS_START_DATE);
```

Comment: Try moving the "TSM.ID > data.ID" into the using part - ie make it part of the "here's the data I'm pulling in". restrict that part. (of course you'll probably need a subquery to do that ;) ) Then, in the "ON" portion, you need to link the "PKs" .. which would be just "TSM.id = data.ID".  If they aren't there, it won't match, and will hit your insert.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it more, why not just use a simple INSERT statement here ?  Merge seems "overkill" for what you need?

Comment: Your `using` clause has a rownum filter but no order by; are you sure the ID you're expecting is returned? But with `>` you might get many more (repeated) matches that you expect anyway, causing duplicate insert attempts, I think; shouldn't that just be `=`?

Comment: Using single insert makes the logic difficult and dont know how to compare the ID and insert only those which is greater than using single insert statement

Comment: @AlexPoole i dont use order by in that because it effect the query execution time. as it has to scan millions of records for that

Comment: Without an order by, which 1000 rows you get is indeterminate.

Comment: Hello Alex i ran the order by clause to get some data for TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC table first. Now i have data. Now i want to modify the query and only want to insert only those data where ID is greater than the PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is "inserting items into table B from A, which don't already exist".

This should do it:

```
  INSERT INTO TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC
    select ID,PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,PROCESS_START_DATE
      from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC@FONIC_RETAIL
     minus 
       select ID,PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,PROCESS_START_DATE
         from TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC;
```

No MERGE needed.

Comment: Hello I have millions of records in my PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC table and i have latest data in my TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC and i only want latest data now to be inserted in this. There is only one way i have to compare the ID from both the table which is sequnce generate and include only those which is greater than.

Comment: Have you tried the insert?  If it does really take too long, (Oracle will use indexes to link those tables for us .. MINUS is probably the most efficient way to do this), however, you could alter it slightly by doing a "select (max(id) from temp_process_monitor_statistic, " and using that as your "id > xxx". Let me post an option for that method as well.

Comment: can you please tell me while changing in your answer what you mean to be ?

Comment: just posted another option - try both, see which one works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

As another option ... you could try this:

```
  INSERT INTO TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC
    select ID,PROCESS_MONITOR_ID,PROCESS_START_DATE
      from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC@FONIC_RETAIL
     where id > (select max(id) from TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC );
```

Restricting it solely based on your largest ID from the target table.

Comment: It runs Ditto thanks but i dont know why the query execution time is longer while using the above statement

Comment: Sorry which one runs longer? the one with ">" or the one using "minus" ? What indexes do you have on the tables? are they partitioned?

Comment: 'minus' query i cant run because it will insert the older data as well and the other query its taking too much time more than 15 minutes. I tries with the Merge query even if it wrong but taking less time to execute

Comment: again. what indexes are on the tables? are the tables partitioned? also, are statistics up to date?

Comment: the statistics are upto date and index are performed on ID

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure it'll run any faster. 15 min for "millions of records" doesn't sound that bad. You might squeeze a bit more out with parallel. And you say the MERGE ran quicker, however, as Alex mentioned in your comments, you include a ROWNUM clause in there - which can dramatically increase speed (since Oracle will stop reading after hitting that many). Try removing the ROWNUM from the MERGE and see if it's still really that fast ;)

Comment: Hello Ditto ok i understood. Please dont misunderstand the query i wrote it was inserting the data initially. Now i can change my query completely and only want to insert ID which is greate than the the PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC

Comment: Ok, so if this helps, you can indicate as such by marking it answered. If you need additional assistance in tuning the query, it might be best to open a new question for that.

Comment: Just be aware that if someone inserts data into PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC while your `INSERT` statement is running, it won't get inserted into TEMP_PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC.  But it would get picked up the next time it ran.

Comment: Hello Mark yes u r right. And for that i am going to run cron jobs for every 5 min. But i did not find a way yet to get the  ID greater than the ID from PROCESS_MONITOR_STATISTIC